# How to stop repeating the values of variable and catch all values?

Tags: c

I am trying to make changes but not able to get the result. What I am trying to do is that I want the list of words to show one by one. But it is showing me the word **Name** again and again.

The second problem is that `listing variable` contains 8 values but the result from the file is showing me 7 values and not showing the amount which is present in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 50

int main(){
    FILE * fr = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    char str[50], file_text[100];
    int one_by_one=0, c, i;
    const static char *listing[] = {"Name", "Date of Birth", "ID card number",
                                    "Phone number","Address", "Account", "Fixing", "Amount"};

    c = fgetc(fr);
    while(c != EOF){
        file_text[one_by_one] = c;
        if(file_text[one_by_one] == ','){
            file_text[one_by_one] = '\0';
            for (i=0; i<2; i++){
                // Here is a problem.                                                                          
                printf("Here is your %s: %s\n", listing[i], file_text);
                one_by_one = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            one_by_one++;
            c = fgetc(fr);
        }
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. This causes a lot of confusion. And use at least 4 spaces or indentation.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<2; i++)` why do you have another `i++` inside the loop body? There is already an `i++` in the `for` statement. And why `2`?

Comment: Your code does not compile and is missing a '}' somewhere

Comment: Sorry Kaylum and possum! No it's working fine. I put `i++` by mistake. Before `for loop` I used `while loop`. That's why I put `i++`

Comment: It looks like the code you pasted is missing a close brace for the while loop.

Comment: Its working fine rallen911

Comment: Why are you closing the file INSIDE the loop?

Comment: Nvm, it just looked like you were closing it inside the loop because you did not indent properly. I have fixed it for you now.

Comment: Changing your code to fix bugs mentioned in comments will confuse readers. This should be avoided. You have removed that extra `i++` and added a `}` silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` gets rest in your loop every time, so will only show it once.  You're incrementing it in the loop as well as at the top of the loop.  What you want is to cycle through the field titles I assume

`fgetc` needs to be pulled out into the main loop so it can update when you encounter `,`

You probably want to check for `,` and `\n` if you're using a csv

Placing a strategic brace the following gives me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fr = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    char file_text[100];
    int one_by_one = 0, c, i;
    const int number_of_fields = 8;
    const static char *listing[] = {"Name", "Date of Birth", "ID card number",
                                    "Phone number", "Address", "Account", "Fixing", "Amount"};

    c = fgetc(fr);
    while (c != EOF) {
        file_text[one_by_one] = c;
        if (file_text[one_by_one] == ',' || file_text[one_by_one] == '\n') {
            file_text[one_by_one] = '\0';
            printf("Here is your %s: %s\n", listing[i], file_text);
            one_by_one = 0;
            i = (i + 1) % number_of_fields;
        } else {
            one_by_one++;
        }
        c = fgetc(fr);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```

sample output from a csv matching your fields.

```
Here is your Name: name
Here is your Date of Birth:  dob
Here is your ID card number:  id
Here is your Phone number:  phone
Here is your Address:  address
Here is your Account:  account
Here is your Fixing:  fixing
Here is your Amount:  amount
Here is your Name: name2
...
```

Comment: Sorry but it is giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: `i` is not initialized.